# Sorting an Object List, on a user defined property with c#

Tags: c#, sorting, delegates

I have an Object (Called MyReading) with 18 properties.
I add instances of this Object to a List

eg:

```
List<MyReading> MyReadingsL = new List<MyReading>();
MyReading O1 = new MyReading();
O1._DateTime = "10";
O1._Value1 = "Hello1";
O1._Value2 = "Hello2";
O1._Value3 = "Hello3";
O1._Value4 = "Hello4";

....etc


MyReadingsL.Add(O1);
```

I need to sort the list of readings by any one of the 18 properties. (The user decides which ones)
I understand i must write a delegate for the Sort() method of the list, to specify my own comparison logic in code.

eg. MyReadingsL.Sort(TheDelegate);

Problem is, i do not want to write 18 delegates for each property that i can *probably* sort on. 
Maybe one delegate, a (Comparison Delegate) accepting (MyReading  x,  MyReading y) , and a string, that indicates the property to be sorted on.

How is this possible?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, you'd probably have to use reflection to find the property from the string though which can be expensive memory wise. Why not just write the compare functions or find out what your users want to sort by?

Comment: If the List<MyReading> is being bound to the UI why not just just what is available from the UI controls: DataGridView etc

Comment: @DGibbs -- if you store the reflected properties, you'll only have to perform the reflection operation once.  That's not going to be expensive.

Comment: @RobLyndon True... I still think the OP would be better off just writing the compare functions though - how long would it honestly take? You'll also have code which is much more readable. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @DGibbs -- a lot of readability comes from decent code layout and naming conventions.  I think the advantage of the reflection-based technique is that once you've done it you never have to revisit it.  You can just add a property to your class and *BOOM*, there it is in the user's dropdown list.

Comment: @RobLyndon Yep, both approaches have their benefits for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy.  Linq already gives you this:

```
MyReadingsL.OrderBy(r => r._Value1);
MyReadingsL.OrderBy(r => r._Value2);
...
MyReadingsL.OrderBy(r => r._Valuen);
...
```

If you want to define an external function that you call in the same way, your signature should look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyReading> GetSortedList(Func<MyReading, string> property) { }
```

To translate from a string into a property, you can define a static data member.

```
public static IDictionary<string, Func<MyReading, string>> Properties = 
    typeof(MyReading).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => prop.Name, p => new Func<MyReading, string>(r => p.GetValue(r)));
```

This static member gives you a dictionary of all the properties in your class, keyed by their identifying strings and giving you access to the delegates that let you perform the Linq operations you need.

Then, given a string `s` that identifies a property, you can call `MyReadingsL.OrderBy(Properties[s])` at very little cost.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by linq. What you'll have to do is pass the string/property you'll want to sort with, and then use the `orderby`.

General example:

```
// Create 10 objects with 2 properties
var num_and_name_list = 
        from num in Enumerable.Range(1,10)
        select new { val=num, name=(""+num+"oeu")};

// Here i'll sort them by the name property.
var sorted_by_name_list = 
        from some_object in num_and_name_list
        orderby some_object.name descending
        select some_object;
```

The results will look like

[image]

So, you'll just have to see how / where you pass your property to sort with.

---

If you need to get the property from the string, you could do something like:

```
// Create 10 objects with 3 properties
var num_and_name_list =
        from num in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        select  new ExtraStringDataPoint ( num, num*2,  ("" + num + "oeu"));

// Hunting your property starts
Type myType = num_and_name_list.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

PropertyInfo order_on_this = null;
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    order_on_this = typeof(ExtraStringDataPoint).GetProperty("Y");
}


// Here i'll sort them by the name property.
var sorted_by_name_list =
        from some_object in num_and_name_list
        orderby order_on_this descending
        select some_object;
```

My `ExtraStringDataPoint` looks like:

```
public class ExtraStringDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    public ExtraStringDataPoint(double x, double y, string s)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Extra = s;
    }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return X +" , " + Y + " , " + Extra;
    }
}
```

In your case , you can just pass the variable you want as a string, like I used "Y".

Comment: I think the crux of the question is how to translate from a user-defined string to a delegate that you can sort the list with.